# Invoking injected method

Tags: javassist

Whenever I create a new method with Javassist using this method

```
public static void addMethod(CtClass targetClass, String code) throws Exception {
    CtNewMethod.make(code, targetClass);
    targetClass.toClass();
    logger.info("Method Successfully created in " + targetClass.getName());
}
```

and later try to invoke it with

```
public static void invokeMethod(CtClass targetClass, String methodName, Object...args) throws Exception {
    Method method = targetClass.getClass().getDeclaredMethod(methodName);
    method.invoke(targetClass, args);
}
```

I get the exception "java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: javassist.CtClassType.testMethod()"

does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The error is thrown because with
`Method method = targetClass.getClass().getDeclaredMethod(methodName);`
you are invoking `getClass()` on a `CtClass` object but you should invoke on class generated by `targetClass.toClass()`.
You have to restructure your code in this way:

```
CtClass targetClass = new CtClass();
addMethod(targetClass, method1Code);
addMethod(targetClass, method2Code);
Class<?> k = targetClass.toClass();
invokeMethod(k, ...);
```

and rewrite

1. `addMethod()` removing `targetClass.toClass()`
2. Change `invokeMethod()`'s first param with a standard `java.lang.Class`